# Error code 81030137 during application update on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

Somehow **updates** for our Windows Phone application (not universal, just silverlight!) are not properly installing the code: **81030137** appears during the installation. Tho when the users do the clean install - it installs just normally. I usually change the application versions in manifest file inside of Visual Studio 2015, so that after uploading package to the store it sees the right version there. I think the problem started appearing after i've upgraded the project from Windows Phone 8.0 to Windows Phone 8.1. The main problem here is that the issue is experienced by ALL the users, who try to update, not any certain ones, which leads to our clients' frustration. I need to find out what can cause the error; already tried the ms support and they've redirected me to the MSDN forums.

My question is: what should i as a developer do(change in a manifest, create a new one.. i dont know) to solve this problem for my customers?

Comment: Did this not work? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdupdate/error-code-81030137/9527477b-19af-4008-becc-c06db1297c46?auth=1

Comment: @O.O this solution is for customers and its not working + i cant ask customers to reset their devices after updates :D The worst part here is that MS itself can't normally answer me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I've found the solution, posting here in case someone will face the same problem:

for Windows Phone 8.1 you need to change the version for the package in 2 places: `WMAppManifest.xml` and `Package.appxmanifest`. The store during the upload process shows the version from `WMAppManifest.xml`, **but(!)** when you download the software and open history tab in store - version from `Package.appxmanifest` is shown. Seems that both versions must be more then the one before uploading the update.